# My rails console shows the same model twice - uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model named `pictures.rb` aka Picture class which should map to pictures table but in rails console it gets displayed twice?

```
irb(main):013:0> @models = ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.collect { |type| type.name }.sort
=> ["Picture", "Picture"]
```

I am trying to use Picture class aka picture.rb model in my ControlPanelController index function

so when I load my index page I get the following error

```
uninitialized constant ControlPanelController::Picture


  def index
    @pictures = Picture.all
  end
```

I am guessing it might be because that Picture model shows up twice in rails console? Not sure.

Comment: Pls post your model filename and contents

Comment: Btw: Not sure how that works for you in $ irb ! You meant to be in $ rails console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it can't find it is your model file name is called pictures.rb.

The filename should be picture.rb (not plural).

It should be:

**app/models/picture.rb:**

```
class Picture< ActiveRecord::Base
...
end
```